# Order management system in the ecommerce website

Tags: django, web, e-commerce, orders, oms

The problem is about the logic of the implementation of an order management system in an e-commerce website

I try to implement an order management system using Django in an e-commerce website can anyone help me in the implementation of the oms in the e-commerce website using Stripe and PayPal in the process of the payment